# How am I able to fix an attribute error when using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributeerror

Write a class named 'Person' with data attributes for a person's name, address, and telephone number.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, n, a, p):
        self.name = n
        self.address = a
        self.phone = p
    
    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n
    
    def set_address(self, a):
        self.address = a
    
    def set_phone(self, p):
        self.phone = p
    
    def get_name(self):
        return 'Customer Name:'
    
    def get_address(self):
        return 'Customer Address:'
    
    def get_phone(self):
        return 'Customer Phone Number:'
    
def main():
    n = input('Enter Customer Name: ')
    a = input('Enter the Customer Address: ')
    p = input('Enter the Customer Phone Number: ')
    
    print(n.get_person())
    print(a.get_address())
    print(p.get_phone())
main()
```

How am I able to fix my attribute error?

Answer (score 0):

First, your errors really should be `TypeError`, because you are calling an instance method from the class:

```py
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = 1
...     def thing(self):
...         return self.bar
...
>>>
>>>
>>> Foo.thing()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: thing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

However, the fix is the same regardless.

You need to create an instance of a class to access its attributes:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 1

# Foo is a class, but it doesn't have a 
# bar attribute. An *instance* of the class
# does

# this raises an attributeError
Foo.bar
AttributeError

# this doesn't, because we created an instance
foo = Foo()
foo.bar
1
```

You need to *create* a person instance, then you can get its attributes:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, address, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone


Person.phone 
# AttributeError

# Create an instance of Person here
tim = Person(name='Tim', address='1234 Main St', phone='555-5555')

# Then you can get Tim's information
tim.phone
'555-5555'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the Person class using something like `person = Person(n, a, p)`. Do this after the input statements of your `main()` function.

Secondly, when printing out the attributes, you need to reference the instance of the Person class that you created (ie. person.get_person(), person.get_address(), etc).

Finally, when calling the get function, make sure those functions are returning the value that you're looking for. The function `get_address()` should return self.address.

Here is my suggestion:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, n, a, p):
        self.name = n
        self.address = a
        self.phone = p
    
    def set_name(self, n):
        self.name = n
    
    def set_address(self, a):
        self.address = a
    
    def set_phone(self, p):
        self.phone = p
    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_address(self):
        return self.address
    
    def get_phone(self):
        return self.phone

def main():
    n = input('Enter Customer Name: ')
    a = input('Enter the Customer Address: ')
    p = input('Enter the Customer Phone Number: ')
    
    person = Person(n, a, p) # create the instance

    # get attributes of instantiated object
    print(person.get_person())
    print(person.get_address())
    print(person.get_phone())

main()
```